# Access NSArray out from Parse query

Tags: ios, parse-platform, nsarray, chat, pfquery

In my query, the `NSLog` is good that writes the good things `NSLog(@"DANS MSG ENVOYE PAR USER : %@", _messages`, but out the query in `viewDidLoad` I can't access the value from my `NSArray`

```
NSLog(@"DESTINATEUR MSG : %@", self.senderMsg);
NSLog(@"EN DEHORS QUERY : %@", self.messages);
```

Have I to implement @synthesize ? What am I doing wrong ?

Here is my code.

ChatViewController.h :

```
#import "MessagesViewController.h"

@interface ChatViewController : MessagesViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *messages;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *destinateurChat;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *senderMsg;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *destinateurMsg;

@end
```

ChatViewController.m :

```
#import "ChatViewController.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import "SVProgressHUD.h"

@interface ChatViewController ()

@end
id message;
NSDate *receiveDate;
NSString *text;
@implementation ChatViewController
@synthesize destinateurMsg = _destinateurMsg;
@synthesize messages = _messages;

#pragma mark - View lifecycle
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Messages";
    PFQuery *query1 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Chat"];
    [query1 whereKey:@"DestinateurId" equalTo:self.destinateurChat];
    [query1 whereKey:@"senderId" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId]];
    PFQuery *query2 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Chat"];
    [query2 whereKey:@"DestinateurId" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId]];
    [query2 whereKey:@"senderId" equalTo:self.destinateurChat];
   // PFQuery *hotelQuery = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[query1, query2]];

    //Message envoyé par l'user
    [query1 findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            _senderMsg = [objects valueForKey:@"text"];
            _messages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            [_messages addObjectsFromArray:_senderMsg];
            NSLog(@"DANS MSG ENVOYE PAR USER : %@", _messages);

    //Messages destiné à l'user
            [query2 findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects2, NSError *error) {
                if (!error) {
                    self.destinateurMsg = objects2;
                    [self.messages addObjectsFromArray:self.destinateurMsg];
                } else {
                    // Log details of the failure
                    NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                }
            }];
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];


    NSLog(@"DESTINATEUR MSG : %@", self.senderMsg);
    NSLog(@"EN DEHORS QUERY : %@", self.messages);
    UIButton *exitButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [exitButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backToInboxView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [exitButton setTitle:@"Inbox" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    exitButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 60, 60);
    [self.view addSubview:exitButton];

   }
```

Comment: Could it be because it's asynchrone?

Comment: @Larme Thanks for the reply. So what I've to do ? I can't access this NSArray out from this query ?

Comment: Are you getting any error or 'self.senderMsg' not printing the array contains ?

Comment: @NimishaPatel No, 0 error, just NSArray is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access `self.senderMsg` and `self.messages` in these lines

```
NSLog(@"DESTINATEUR MSG : %@", self.senderMsg);
NSLog(@"EN DEHORS QUERY : %@", self.messages);
```

because its executed before the Asynchronous request is completed.
`[query1 findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:]` is an asynchronous function that is excecuted in a background thread. After calling those functions the execution inside viewDidLoad continues to the end of the function. At that time the arrays will be empty in the NSLog.

If you want to use the values of the array use it inside the findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock.

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
  if (!error) {
       // You can use it in this block.
       // Reload Data here like [self.tableView reloadData]
  }
}]
```

Comment: Ok, I've understand why it doesn't work.
But, there is no way to use it out findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ?
Because I've to use it in other method :
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.messages.count;
}
and
- (NSString *)textForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return [self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

Comment: call `[self.tableview reloadData]` inside the `[query2 findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock]`.

Comment: Finding objects in the background will only allow you to use the values after the completion block has assigned them. When you tell something to execute in the background, it gets handed off to another thread and the original process continues executing immediately. Because of this, your values are not yet assigned where you are trying to use them. When your completion block is called, this is your notification that the values are populated and available for use -- change your control flow to use them only after this happens.